# How to use Mercurial repo on Wercker?

Tags: mercurial, repository, continuous-integration, bitbucket, wercker

I cannot see my Bitbucket Mercurial repositories on Wercker.
Any idea how to be able to view them?
Do I need to convert them to Git to be able to use Wercker?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality doesn't exist (yet);  see the relevant feature request [here](https://wercker.uservoice.com/forums/181077-general/suggestions/6363874-add-mercurial-support-esp-at-bitbucket) on uservoice.